# Array animation along path

Tags: animation, modifiers, constraints

I have a single curve object and while I can set an array of objects to follow the path, I seem unable to combine this with a Follow Path constraint (as I wish to have them follow that path animated).

Thanks~

--- Edit: Pictures ---
At frame 1 (looks okay): [image: Frame 1]
At frame 5 (entirely messed up): [image: Frame 5]
Modifiers & Constraints:
[image: Modifiers] [image: Constraints]

Comment: it probably has unexpected result as you have 2 cumulated effects, the follow path movement, which is not straight, and how the curve bend the object when it moves along it. Why not just making it move without Follow Path, along X or Y or Z?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information, also add images that show what you are doing and how you are setting up the modifiers.